# am I allowed to ask a user to be an editor for me

Tags: discussion, editing

I am legitimately curious because if I find someone who understands me can I ask them to edit all my questions that others might not understand?

Comment: I don't know if I have the correct tags for this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you could *ask*.  I don't know if it would help much though.

Due to the nature of this site, users are able to edit, or propose edits, to other users' posts.  There's nothing inherently wrong with asking if users (or I guess one particular user) would be willing to edit your questions to make them understandable.

On the other hand, I don't think it's a particularly good idea, and I doubt you would have much luck with this plan.  There's no reason why you *couldn't* do this, according to site policies that I am aware of; and no technical limitations.

There are several hurdles to overcome, and I believe they would make this practically useless:

First is finding someone willing to do this.  Members of this community are volunteering their time, generally because they enjoy thinking about physics in their free time and are willing to share that knowledge.  I don't think many people on this site would want to spend time reading through your questions and fixing them for you.  You may have some luck on a case-by-case basis; but I am very doubtful you would find a willing user who would want to edit *all* of your questions.

This brings me to the second point - the process of how you would find someone to do this.  The only decent method I can think of would be using the Chat to see if there is anyone willing to help.  I have my doubts you would find anyone there willing to do this for all your questions.  Asking for this anywhere else on this site (such as questions/comments/answers) is something to avoid.  It wouldn't really be an appropriate use of these features, and I doubt it would be successful even if people read it.

The third issue is that having someone edit your questions after the fact may not help you very much.  If the question gets more attention in it's unedited format, it could receive downvotes and other negative feedback that may be hard to reverse if enough users don't notice the edit.

**TL;DR** In theory, you can *ask*; but I have my doubts you would find much help, and you need to make sure you are asking in an appropriate way.

Comment: Internet time is another huge obstacle. We have no idea about most geographic locations and routines, so there's no knowing when people log in.

Comment: thank you I have a freind I can get from a site they helped me build but I have to ask them to come over in my open time