# my reputation increases faster as I get more reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation

I don't know if it is because of my latest question on main or because of all good help I am getting. can someone tell me if there is a reason I get more faster as I obtain more?

Comment: Without more context, I want to say partially coincidence, and partially being used to the site.  I don't really know if this needed to be a question on meta though...

Comment: You don't have enough experimental data for a categoric statement. I think it is just coincidence. In your rep, your posts are yet automatically reviewed, and some first-post reviewers like to give upvotes. Most upvotes you collect after the first days of your posts. Later, you will collect roughly so many on the long term.

Comment: The effect that rep1 users are handled a little bit more harshly as it would be needed, yes it exists, but it is not so strong that it would be visible in 6-10 upvotes. The main reason of the hard beginning time of the rep1 users is that they don't know the optimal formulation, formatting, style and topicality customs enough well.

Comment: on 3 consecutive days my rep was much higher than the previous

Comment: @Luna How about the option, that your questions are good? :-)

Comment: idk, do you think some some of or all of my questions are good?

Comment: have you by any chance seen my first question?

Comment: @Luna I can't see deleted questions, so I can see only your first question which wasn't deleted. [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454952/32426). You have 5 ups and 5 downvotes. For upvotes to a question you get 5 rep. For downs you lose 2. This results a net reputation gain of $\approx$ 15 (rep can't go below 1, so downs what you've got with 1 rep don't count).

Comment: I was only asking if you have read it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've been on this site for a sum total of two weeks. That is nowhere near enough data to say *anything* conclusive.

In particular, the only backing in [your reputation tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/220173/luna?tab=reputation) for the observation that you report is the linear progression from January 27 through January 29:

> [image]

Note that this growth trend is already on some shaky ground.

The simplest explanation that you're getting more reputation over the last couple of days is that your [fourth question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/457644/why-does-sound-behave-differently-in-water-than-in-air) is better than the previous three.

Seriously, though: take it easy. Read as many questions and answers as you can, use them to write the best questions and answers as you can, take your time when writing posts, and worry about the details of site mechanics like reputation later.

Comment: note that the fourth also was random  and the first was on an experiment that made me say "my teachers lied the same side of two magnets can attract"

Answer (score 5):

[Emilio Pisanty's answer](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11055) covers your specific case pretty well, but it's worth addressing the question

> *"[Is there] a reason I get more faster as I obtain more?"*

I think it's pretty trivial/general and there's no real need to ask that kind of thing on meta. Obviously, if you participate at almost *anything* for some time, you'll get the hang of it and start doing it better. The rep gained is an indication that you've put together a well-received question ([this one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457644)), and while that may simply be coincidence, it may be because you have a better idea of how to ask. That being said, there is some speculation (cf. [this Meta SE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322722) and links therein) that people are less reluctant to upvote a post by a high-rep user, but in your case (70 rep), I doubt that it's a significant factor.

Still, you could relax with the meta posts... questions like this one, [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11046), [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10997), and [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11008) are the kind of thing which you could/would answer yourself if you hang around the site observing interactions and questions for a couple of weeks and exploring the help center a bit. Posting everything on meta is really not necessary, in fact at a certain stage it becomes harmful because it fills up the front page, hiding important stuff and consuming peoples' time. For instance, this week saw a lot of complaints and poorly thought out feature-suggestions (I make that claim since they were heavily downvoted), a few of which were yours, and some stuff which I feel could have spent some time on top ([this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11050) and [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11001)) got submerged. Furthermore, if you have such a large number of meta posts, people will start wondering if you're relying on the 'meta effect' (whereby you draw attention to your posts by 'advertising' them on meta) to get votes, and it will become difficult for people to assume good faith. SE has a complex privilege and moderation system, which can have a big impact on usage patterns, so it's understandable that you're curious. But please, observe, speculate, and research *before* asking everything on meta.

<sub>On a side note, questions which get you rep are, more often than not, *not good questions*. A key feature of most high-scoring questions is *accessibility*, not quality, due to the HNQ (Hot Network Question) effect. So perhaps if you spend some months/years around and start asking questions which are of interest primarily to people who specifically study physics, the upvotes will slow down.</sub>

Comment: I am a analytical person so for me it is different

Comment: I'd go a bit beyond your last sentence - posting everything on meta isn't just unnecessary - it is actively a Bad Thing (past a certain point, which isn't that far off from the current count). It's expecting others to fill in the gaps of your understanding of the site mechanics and site culture that you're expected to get the hang of on your own. Being an "analytical person" doesn't get you off the hook on anything.

Comment: what I mean is I analyze everything so I notice numbers easily

Comment: @Luna 'Noticing numbers easily' isn't a strong justification either: all new users _and_ old new users notice rep because when we try to perform certain actions, we're sometimes shown messages saying we don't have the rep to do that. And when we gain rep, there's a big flashing green number at the top of the page. It's hard to miss. You need to look at the links given to you: in every place where a rep number shows up, there's a link to the privileges page of the help center. Read that, and think about how it can be earned and what it's supposed to indicate _before_ asking on meta.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Indeed, I was hesitant to say that it's actually bad, though I felt that way. I do believe it's an important point, so I've edited the answer to talk some more about the reasons why posting so much on meta is unhelpful, in case comments get wiped or something.

Comment: @Luna Next time you come up with a question like that, spend some time looking through some [help center](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) pages, or search around the Meta, maybe looking for a relevant tag.  It's not a bad thing that you have questions about the site.  You need to spend more time trying to answer those questions on your own though.

Comment: I analyze data for a living so I notice it instantly

Comment: @Luna ...You analyze data for a living, but you felt it was worth asking a meta question about a practically arbitrary pattern with an extremely limited sample size?

Comment: arbitrary no necicary possibly

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add another potential cause:
Occasionally when you post questions or answers, reputation gains trickle in every once in a while for a longer amount of time, so it's the amount of good questions and answers that boost the speed of your reputation gains and not the reputation itself.

I believe that in your case Emilio's answer is the accurate one, but if you notice an increased rep gain in the future, this might be another possibility.